# Add Featured Image and Title to wp_nav_menu items

Tags: menus, filters

I like this solution from Ahmad M, a lot, but how do I add images in addition to titles, instead of replacing titles? (Sorry, I'm still pretty new to PHP and Stackexchange).

[Pulling Featured Images in to a WordPress Menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87017/pulling-featured-images-in-to-a-wordpress-menu)

I mostly figured it out. I'm using Ahmad M's filter but needed to add ".$menu_object->title" to the thumbnail so now it looks like:

```
$menu_object->title = has_post_thumbnail($menu_object->object_id) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($menu_object->object_id, 'full') .  $menu_object->title .  : $menu_object->title;
```

Now my challenge is that I only want to add it to third level menu items (child of a child of a parent).

Comment: I understand that you want to show featured image with each of your menu link. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. Ahma M's solution works really well, but I needed to modify it. I figured out how to do that, but now I need to make it work only third level menu items.

Comment: Only for third level menus?

Comment: Yes. I would like to understand how to set a parameter for any given level, but for my current project, I need third level menu items.

Comment: can you please share the html you are going to use for same..

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get you the featured image for 3rd level of your navbar.
You, have to pass the **nav-menu id** within `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`. It will get you the menu list ([For more details](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)).

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(9); /*/Pass Nav Menu_id or Name*/
        $previousMenuParent = $level = 0;
        foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {

            if($menu->menu_item_parent == 0)
            {
                $level = 0;
                echo '<li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';
            }
            elseif($menu->menu_item_parent != '' && $menu->menu_item_parent != $previousMenuParent)
            {
                $level++;
                echo '<ul class="submenu">';
                echo '<li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';
                $previousMenuParent = $menu->menu_item_parent;
            }
            elseif($previousMenuParent == $menu->menu_item_parent)
            {
                echo '</li><li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">';
                if($level == 3)
                {
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->ID);
                }
                echo $menu->title .'</a>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to give it a try. I like how Ahmad M used a filter in the original post referenced, above. I'll see if I can adapt your work here into a filter. Original question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87017/pulling-featured-images-in-to-a-wordpress-menu